# Get data from MariaDB with nodejs and send them to an html page (Express JS)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, mariadb

I need to get some data from a local Maria database, and send them to an HTML table, to build a calendar with some activitys.
I'm using Express JS to redirect users to a specific HTML page.

This is my file tructure:

```
NODE
|
|- app.js

PUBLIC
|
|- RESOURCES
   |
   |- PROPS
   |  |
   |  |- CSS
   |     |
   |     |- index.css
   |- SCRIPTS
      |
      |- index.js

index.html
foo.html
```

This is an example of the **app.js**:

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express();
const path = require("path");

app.use(express.static("../public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/../index.html"));
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("App listening on port 5000!");
});
```

I simply need to access MariaDB when i'm loading a specific HTML file, like **/about**,
get some data, and send them to a JS function to edit this table.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: i don't really know how to start..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a templating engine to render your view with your data. Otherwise you could create an api endpoint that responds with the mariadb data and send a request using Javascript.